# How to tunnel all network communication?

Tags: networking, vpn, tunneling

I'm looking for a way to tunnel all network communication from my laptop through another computer. I can control the software on both the laptop and the computer. The connection between them should be encrypted.

Which technique should I use? VPN seems out of the question, as I wouldn't want my laptop to show up on the other computer's LAN.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if this was a bad question! Should I supply more info?

Comment: It's off topic for this site. That's the primary reason why it's a bad question. Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using SSH and [proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) and socks 5 tunneling. All you need is to set up openssh on the computer.